# PostgreSQL - Casting JSON string to INTERVAL returns incorrect value

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I am observing a weird behaviour on Postgres server when casting a JSON string into INTERVAL type. I tried it out on Postgres v9, v10, v11 and got the same results on each.

Example:

```
select '{"minutes": 20, "hours":10}'::interval;

+----------+
| interval |
+----------+
| 20:00:10 |
+----------+
(1 row)
```

No errors, warnings, nothing. Postgres does not complain but gives back an incorrect result. Why does it behave like this?

On the other hand, these examples return error:

```
select '{}'::interval;

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "{}"
LINE 1: select '{}'::interval;
               ^

select '{"blahblah": 10}'::interval;

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "{"blahblah": 10}"
LINE 1: select '{"blahblah": 10}'::interval;
               ^
```

I know how to mitigate the issue. Here I just want to understand why it behaves like this.

Comment: You aren't casting a JSON, you are casting a `text` value - but that doesn't make it less surprising

Comment: Updated the title to say 'JSON string'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question. It looks like Postgres is simply parsing the text in a following way:

`{"minutes": 20, "hours":10}`

`20` is followed by `hours` so it becomes `20 hours`. `10` is not followed by anything so it becomes `10 seconds`. Final result is `20:00:10`.

Another example:
`select '{hours 20 !!!!! d 10 ::: s}'::interval;`

`20` is followed by `d` and becomes `20 days`. `10` is followed by `s` and becomes `10 seconds`. Final result is `20 days 00:00:10`.